# How to get correct $http error code, instead of -1?

Tags: angularjs, https

I use `$http` to retrieve data from server. In case error happen, all `statusCode = -1`. I cannot get correct `errorCode` to handle in client. I don't have permission to update server code.

```
$http(options).then(function (response) {
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        resolve(response.data);
                    } else {
                        exceptionHandler(response);
                    }
                }, function (error) {
                    exceptionHandler(error);
                });
```

`console.log` is put on `exceptionHandler` function.

Please help me get correct error code. Many thanks.

[image: Error 404]

[image: Error 403]

[image: Error 500]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the responses you have shown, the 404 error is available as `error.status` but the other two responses were denied access by your browser when it performed the preflight OPTIONS request.

In that case the browser returns a status of -1 to indicate that the request was aborted. There is no HTTP status code for your request because it was never sent. The status 500 shown in the console log is not made available to any javascript code.

You should handle a status of -1 as indicating that no response was received from the server, either because it was never sent (this case), or because it was sent but timed out.